# How to show all registred users and their groups with one command?

Tags: users, group

I was writing a test on basic Unix commands etc, and there was a question show all registered users and their groups with one command. At the same time I can't use `getent` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is for example with `awk` and reading `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group` (I assume you don't need system users and I am trying to exclude them and locked users):

```
awk -F":" 'NR==FNR {
    if ($2 !~ /\!/ && $2 !~ /\*/) {
        m[$1] = "";
    }
    next;
}
{
    for (i in m) {
        if ($4 ~ i || $1 == i) {
            m[i] = m[i] $1 " ";
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (i in m) {
        print i ":", m[i];
    }
}' /etc/shadow /etc/group
```

You can remove `if ($2 !~ /\!/ && $2 !~ /\*/)` condition to list all user accounts, and also note that existence of `!` or `*` in `/etc/shadow` means the user is not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means e.g. key based login).

Answer (score 1):

cat /etc/passwd (filter the contents with grep as per your requirements)

Here you go: `awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd | while read -r line; do id "$line"; done`

Comment: That shows the primary group but doesn't include secondary group memberships

Comment: pipe the first column of user names to "id" command